# I have to get the group which is having more "True" values than its "False" values from the given Dataframe:

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-science

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['group1','group1','group2','group1','group2',group1','group2','group2','group2','group1'],'B':['true','true','true','false','false','false','fasle','true','fasle','true']})
```

I tried to make it groupwise by using groupby function but that didn't work. Please help me out with this question.

EDIT: code

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use crosstab and query:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['group1','group1','group2','group1','group2','group1',
                                         'group2','group2','group2','group1'],
  'B':['true','true','true','false','false','false','false','true','false','true']})
```

---

```
pd.crosstab(df['A'],df['B']).query("true>false").index
#Index(['group1'], dtype='object', name='A')
```

If values in column `B` are boolean and not strings:

```
pd.crosstab(df['A'],df['B']).loc[lambda x:x[True]>x[False]].index
```

Answer (score 1):

Longer code, but may be faster than `pd.crosstab` :

```
df.groupby(["A", "B"]).size().unstack().loc[lambda x: x.true.gt(x.false)].index

Index(['group1'], dtype='object', name='A')
```